# ¿Cómo hacer para que mis tablas con kable se rendericen en word como tablas? R markdown

Tags: r, table, r-markdown

En mi script de R markdown realizo tablas con la función kable que en la visualización de R se ven bien, pero cuando renderizo el archivo a un word me aparece como texto simple. Probé agregando en el encabezado results='asis' y no me resultó tampoco.

Adjunto fotos de cómo se ve en R markdown y cómo se ve en word

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia el paquete `kableExtra` no funciona del todo bien la salida `word`, de hecho en el sitio del paquete sugieren hacer una salida `HTML` y copiar y pegar la tabla en el documento `word`. Una posibilidad que funciona razonablemente bien es configurar un formato más amigable para la conversión, por ejemplo:

````
```{r}
kable(head(mtcars), format = "markdown")
```
````

Sino la otra es usar `flextable` que renderiza las tablas en `word` mucho mejor y tiene múltiples configuraciones de estilos y formatos ([documentación](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/index.html)):

````
```{r}
library(flextable)
flextable(head(mtcars))
```
````